# How to install jasmine in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jasmine

For js testing, I need to install jasmine BDD framework in eclipse but don't know how to install in Eclipse. Also searched in the market place nothing is related to that. Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Have you tried it? 
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jas-mine-plugin-eclipse-ide

Comment: Yes searched that in market place also.

Comment: JAS-mine != jasmine